# Cannot retract downvotes using the Android application

Tags: bug, android-app

Most of us are probably aware of the shortcomings of the Android portal to Stack Overflow. But I have been stung so many times by this issue that I thought that it made sense to raise it

If I upvote a post using the Android application then there is no way to retract that vote. Tapping the up-arrow produces a message "You have already voted on this post", while a tap on the down-arrow or in the score number produce nothing

I realise that the Android interface is essentially an alpha (although it has been published without comment) but voting is central to Stack Overflow, and it is essential that this functionality is fixed

I'm using a 64GB Pixel C running Android 7.0 build NRD90M. It's hard *not* to have the latest build of all applications, but my current build of the Stack Exchange app is **version code: 183, version name: 1.0.85**

Comment: Hmm, works as expected for me. You might want to include your device and OS details in your post. You might also make sure you're using the latest version of the app.

Comment: Yeah, this is a a really annoying bug.  If you refresh the view, you *should* be able to reverse the vote.  For some reason the arrows get stuck after clicking.

Comment: No repro; running on a Nexus 6P with Android 7 build NRD90U.  You sure the vote you tried to reverse was within the time limit?

Comment: I thought meta was for discussion & bugs effecting the whole site, rather than platform-specific tools.

Comment: @Burt_Harris ....and where else do we put it then?

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC, not being an android user I don't know, and perhaps I'm wrong, but it seems to me that there should be a an app-specific bug tracking tools somewhere.

Comment: The android-app tag says *Questions about the Android app should be asked on Meta Stack Exchange.* so in theory they should go there @Burt_Harris but users can report bugs on their own meta site so this is a bit of a grey area.